# What are the Real time Usage of Spring Interceptor?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, interceptor

I am Studying about Spring Interceptors, I know it works as a front Controller, It can serve Some requests and some responses or all, and in the flow of execution, Requests goes to the Interceptor first before calling controller.

But I want to know more about it, Like, what are the real-time Scenarios or Usage of it. for example, we can use it for session Management, But I want to know more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some Real-Time Usage of Interceptor :

- Maintaining Session / Session Management.
- Email Shoot & Database Check/logging.
- Authentication & Authorization Validations.
- Request Time Calculations. / Performance tunning.
  Etc.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to mention 2 facts about interceptors before mentioning where it could be used in a web application -

- In spring interceptor is something that sits between the DispatecherServlet and Controller (you already know it)
- The Interceptor interface is like -

> ```
> public interface HandlerInterceptor {
>   boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler);
>   void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView mav);
>   void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServeletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex);
> }
> ```

[image]

Based on the above facts you can use interceptor in the following situations -

- You can do extra work before rendering the view. For example, a web page can be handled when the Global Navigation Bar (GNB) requires items to be exposed differently depending on its permissions.
- Can mimic AOP. `@RequestMappingIf` the declaration specifies a request for a request, then it HandlerMethod(`@Controller`)will be called with a handler HandlerMethod. HandlerMethodBy identifying additional information, such as method signatures, you can determine whether to run the logic. So that you can use interceptor as loggin (intercepting the `HttpServletRequest`), modify the JSON or validate it before or after going to the controller.

Comment: I know what you said but, I am asking about the real-time usage of it. Could you please explain more about it @Razib .